# HTTP 400 Request Headers Too Long when viewing profile images in CSWP

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, my-site, cswp

I have a Content Search Web Part teed up in a SharePoint Online site that is returning just people results. The search is looking for users within a specific department. This is working great as I am getting the set of people I expect.

The problem I am having, however, is all of the profile image requests are producing "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long." errors. This is occurring in FF, IE, and Chrome. 
[image: Image of CSWP showing broken profile images.]

Looks like all of the images requests are going back to my sites, e.g.: https://foo-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/foo_bar.jpg. Copying URLs directly into the browser produces the same result.

I have tried multiple things, including clearing cache, cookies, etc. for all time, opening in an incognito/private window, all to no effect. My client WAS experiencing this as well, but yesterday it suddenly started working for him. I'm still stuck with the above result, however.

Additionally, I did find this post that also speaks to the same issue, though there at this point is no resolution: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Chrome-quot-400-Request-Too-Long-quot-when-navigating-to-profile/td-p/37008

Has anyone in this community run into this problem, and if so, is there a work around?

Comment: I see this on occasion too (was one to comment in the linked TC thread). Yeah, no resolution as of yet.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TrevorSeward. Kind of figured it was a long shot. It seems to be a longer-term issue with my account for some reason. Been going on for over a week now.

Comment: As I noted in the TC thread, deleting the cookies works for this in a general sense. I'm not saying that'll fix your specific issue, though. It might be worth opening a case through the O365 Admin Portal.